# Outlook folder management - How do I delete emails 10 days or older from a folder in outlook automatically?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a shared Outlook mailbox which receives multiple reports.  I use rules to move these reports into folders by report name.  I would like to delete reports which are over 10 days older from these folders.  Is there an automated way to manage these folders and emails?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use AutoArchive

1. Select the folder you want this to happen in
2. Click "AutoArchive Settings" button -> `Archive this folder using these settings`
3. Set `Clean out items older than` to `10 Days`
4. Change radio selection to `Permanently delete old items`

Note:  By default, Autoarchive globally runs every 14 days, so to get it to run every day, you'd have to go to File->Options->Advanced->Auto Archive Settings and change how often to run it.

Comment: Coming here in 2022, and oh, surprise: it seems that Outlook doesn't have that "AutoArchive" thing any more.

Comment: Okay, addendum: it still exists in the Windows client, but not in the Web or MacOs outlook client. Grmpf.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Outlook Archive/Auto Archive feature.  This will allow you to do exactly what you are asking for.  The means of setting this up varies between different versions of Outlook and you don't specify which version you mean, but the tutorials [here](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/outlook2007Tutorials/autoArchiveAndManuallyArchiveEmails.php) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/file-or-archive-your-email-messages-RZ001026647.aspx) should give you some guidance.